# RV32I ASM lw command output?

Tags: arrays, assembly, riscv

In the given code the result of lw t2, 8(t0) should be 2 or ?
After that the 2 will be shifted left by 2 Bytes = 8.
But the add command is what confuses me. By my understanding we just add the 8 back to numbers.
(1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,**8**)
And if we load the first index of numbers in t3 there should be an 8 but the output is 2...

```
.data
numbers: .word 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55

.text
addi t1, x0, 4
la t0, numbers
lw t2, 8(t0)
slli t2, t2, 2
add t0,t0,t2
lw t3, 0(t0)
```

Comment: Each word is 4 bytes wide, and `0(t0)` is the first element.  So yes, `numbers+8` is the address of the `2` element in the array.  Also, `2<<2` is 8, so it's the same address as the first load.

Comment: _"But the add command is what confuses me. By my understanding we just add the 8 back to numbers. (1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,8)"_. The `add` doesn't write anything back to memory. It just adds the values in registers $t0 and $t2 and stores the sum in $t0. In this case the two values being summed are `(the address of) numbers` and `8`.

Comment: @Michael, Peter Cordes Thank you both for your answers, this helped me a lot.